# Is run_in_executor optimized for running in a loop with coroutines?

Tags: python-asyncio

It strikes me that the `run_in_executor()` method of the `asyncio` library *belongs* to a `loop` object.

In particular, what would be the difference if I chose to run a second thread alongside an async event loop the "usual" way, by `import threading`, `t = threading.Thread(target=...)`, `t.start()`?

Perhaps the answer is by using the `asyncio` module there are low level optimizations which can be made at runtime if the loop knows about additional threads?

Comment: `run_in_executor`, returns an await-able future. This is not possible (or easily possible) with `threading.Thread`

Comment: Nothing about `asyncio` is optimized, and the fact that this is a method of a `loop` is just due to the randomness of this module. There's no reason why this should be a method of the loop. The whole executor thing was invented only for this method and isn't used anywhere else. You'd be probably better off just running what you need in threads, w/o `asyncio`.

Comment: `run_in_executor` is used to manage threads from within an event loop. To this end, it needs to wrap the thread into a Future, which needs to be assigned to an event loop (in one way or another). The reason the method is stored directly in a `loop` object is probably historical. It might as well have been `asyncio.run_in_executor` (which I  accidentally wrote many times), where the loop object is obtained automatically.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can always start another thread manually, but then you are responsible for giving it work, e.g. using a queue. In Python 3 [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) provide a convenient API for offloading tasks to a thread pool, which it calls executor. Its [`submit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) method takes a function, gives it to a thread in the pool to run it, and immediately returns a handle that will provide the result (or propagate an exception) when it is ready.

[`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) delivers the same convenience to asyncio. Remember that you're not supposed to run any blocking code inside asyncio - for example `time.sleep()` is forbidden, because it blocks the whole event loop. `run_in_executor` allows you to side-step that rule. For example:

```
async def sleep_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print('going to sleep')
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 5)
    #time.sleep(5)
    print('waking up')

async def parallel():
    # run two sleep_tests in parallel and wait until both finish
    await asyncio.gather(sleep_test(), sleep_test())

asyncio.run(parallel())
```

Running this code shows that both instances of the coroutine sleep in parallel. If we used `time.sleep()` directly, they would sleep in series because the sleep would block the event loop.

This example is of course silly because there is [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) that suspends a coroutine without spending a slot in a thread pool, but it shows the basic idea. Realistic use cases for `run_in_executor` include:

- integrating CPU-bound code, such as numpy or pandas calculations, into an asyncio program
- legacy blocking code that hasn't yet been ported to asyncio
- non-legacy code that is blocking because it relies on APIs that just don't provide non-blocking versions - e.g. proprietary database drivers, or blocking OS-level calls such as those for file system access

Comment: just make sure you use `ProcessPoolExecutor` for CPU-bound code.

Comment: @Ben that depends whether this code releases the GIL or not. NumPy code does, so using multithreading (ThreadPoolExecutor with loop.run_in_executor) is perfect for it. In any other cases related to asyncio, there is a wonderful library called AioPool with async interface (e.g. AioProcess) from aio-libs stack. Highly recommend

Comment: I wish all of these could be added eventually to official python docs)

Comment: Hi folks, I cannot find a way to achieve the same purpose, but with preexisting long running daemon process. ProcessPoolExecutor seems to spawn process on the fly and doesn't account for scenarios where I need to load chunks of data ahead of time because they don't fit a single process. Perhaps I should create the executor in advance and load data there ? But then run_in_executor seems to except the process to be done, while I want to keep them running

Comment: @EricBurel That sounds like material for a new question. Please be sure to carefully describe what you want to achieve, and provide a minimal reproducible example (adding sleeps to substitute for "work" etc.).