# How to pass async function to run_in_executor

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to pass `some_async_func` function to [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).
In the following example I program executes with the following warning:

> coroutine 'some_async_func' was never awaited

Would anyone of you know if it's possible to pass async function to `run_in_executor`?

I am trying to write a program which will run X async coroutines in Y number of threads.

```
import asyncio
import random
from threading import Thread, get_ident


async def some_async_func(num):
    #
    # Many other async functions is called here.
    # I simplified this function just to execute 'sleep'.
    #

    ident = get_ident()
    print(f"produce: {num} in thread {ident}", flush=True)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0, 0.5))
    return {ident: num}


async def large_func():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_async_func, 1)


def side_thread():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(large_func())
    loop.close()


t1 = Thread(target=side_thread, args=(), daemon=True)
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is run\_in\_executor optimized for running in a loop with coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027940/is-run-in-executor-optimized-for-running-in-a-loop-with-coroutines)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me to write a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I implemented a sync wrapper for async function and passed it as follows:

```
def async_func_wrapper():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(some_async_func(10))
    loop.close()
    return results

[...] 
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, async_func_wrapper)
```